# Is GVR Unity SDK v1.30.0, the latest version available..Do it had any issues

Tags: google-vr, google-vr-sdk

- Is GVR Unity SDK v1.10.0 the first version released.
- Which is the best version among the versions released.

Answer (score 1):

The first version of GVR for unity was v0.4.

The latest version- GVR Unity SDK v1.60.0 has released 7 days ago.

I am using this for last 5 days now and all seems to be fine.